# How to get exact place details by using lat,lng of only one place using Google place API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-places-api

I want place details especially address using the only lat,lng coordinate using Google place APIs. 
I tried nearbysearch, text search and radar search, but it requires radius also.  Then I tried to geocode API but it is giving details of more than one place, and I want exactly one place details.

So is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. install twitter gem: `gem 'twitter'`

**Create Controller:**

```
class Api::MapController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def show
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = "your_consumer_key"
      config.consumer_secret     = "your_consumer_secret"
      config.access_token        = "your_access_token"
      config.access_token_secret = "your_access_token_secret"
    end

    #center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}, 
    latitude = params[:lat]
    longitude = params[:lng]

    #str = '31.515181,74.345034,10km'
    str = "#{latitude.to_s},#{longitude.to_s},10km"

    @search_results = client.search( '', geocode: str ).take(15)

    render json: @search_results
 end
end
```

you can set 0kM if 1 result is required. and pass query for specific result in `client.search( 'Coffe Shops', geocode: str ).take(15)` method

**Finally add this Javascript add and show markers on google map**

```
computed_latitude = 150.644;
computed_longitude = -34.397;

map = null;

function initMap() {
    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            computed_latitude = pos.lat;
            computed_longitude = pos.lng;

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: computed_latitude, lng: computed_longitude},
                zoom: 6
            });

            // fetch tweets
            console.log('Fetching tweets now...');
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:3000/api/map/show", // Route to the Script Controller method
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {lat: computed_latitude, lng: computed_longitude}, // This goes to Controller in params hash, i.e. params[:file_name]
                complete: function () {
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    console.log('Got the tweets... Drawing marker.');
                    var marker = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        if (!($.isEmptyObject(data[i].geo))) {
                            var computed_latitude = data[i].geo.coordinates[0];
                            var computed_longitude = data[i].geo.coordinates[1];
                            myLatlng = {lat: computed_latitude, lng: computed_longitude};
                            marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: myLatlng,
                                map: map,
                                title: data[i].text
                            });
                           var id = data[i].id_str;
                           var name = data[i].user.screen_name;
                            function some_function(name, id) {
                                                window.location = 'https://twitter.com/'+ name  + '/status/' + id ;
                                                     };

                        marker[i].addListener("click", function(){
                        some_function(name, id);
                        }, false);


                        }

                    }
                },

                error: function () {
                    alert("Ajax error!")
                }
            });
        }, function () {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
```

**What it does in my case:**

It get user location then send `Long`, `Lat` to `api/map_controller.rb` then using `Twitter` Gem. it searched nearby public tweets within radius of 10km. with no query string. the controller respond in JSON format to javascript based google map. then it appends tweets to map.